# Keith wood Jquery Countdown Display alert message just before 5 seconds of the time remaining?

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

http://jsfiddle.net/shadsaleem/XSceK/6/

I want to alert a message when 5 seconds are remaining.

My main aim is to display a message to the user before end of his time that he has 5 more seconds.
can anyone help me with that?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {
       var austDay = new Date();

       $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until:+10});

      });

</script>

<div id="defaultCountdown" align="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the ticks to a function which will check the time left and throw an alert

Commented out your new date for simplicity. Set the countdown to run for 10seconds, and have a watch method for every tick. In that method we check if seconds = 5 and if so alert.

```
//var austDay=new Date()
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: 10, compact:true, onTick: warnUser});

function warnUser(periods) { 
   if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) == 5) { 
      alert("Five seconds remaining!"); 
   } 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XSceK/9/

The plugin website has numerous examples. http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. Click the tabs to explore.

Cheers.